# Totally Bounded Metric Spaces And Sequences

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Prove that every sequence in a totally bounded metric space has a Cauchy's subsequence.
$$$$Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space and $a_n$ be a sequence then as $a_n$ is a subset of $X$ and as $X$ is totally bounded, so $a_n$ is also totally bounded. Hence chose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, then there exists a finite number of open balls say $$B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, ....., B_k$$ of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ which cover $a_n$. Now atleast one of them say $B_{k_0}$ contains infinite number of terms of $a_n$. Now this subsequence of $a_n$ in $B_{k_0}$ is a subset of $a_n$ and hence it is also totally bounded. So for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$ there exists a finite number of open balls say $$C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, ......, C_m$$ of radius $\frac{1}{4}$ which cover this subsequence. Now against atleast one of these open balls say $C_{m_0}$ contains an infinite number of terms of this subsequence. Continuing in this way in every step chose $x_1$ from $B_{k_0}$, having least index, then chose $x_2$ from $C_{m_0}$ having least index, then we claim that this subsequence of $a_n$ is Cauchy's Subsequence. Now for any given $\epsilon$ chose $N$ such that $$\frac{1}{2^{N-1}} < \epsilon$$. Now as in the $n$th step the ball which contains infinite number of terms of the sequence has radius less than $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and hence $$d(x, y) < \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$ for every $x, y$ in that ball. So for every $m, n \geq N$ we have $$d(x_n, x_m) < \frac{1}{2^{N-1}} <\epsilon $$, and hence this sequence has a Cauchy's Subsequence.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: It could be stated more clearly, but yes, it’s correct.